# How to redirect button that is inside Html.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this View which displays 3 text boxes and a drop down list for displaying nationalities. The form itself works just fine, posts back to the controller and nothing is wrong. However what i want is, say a nationality is not present in the drop down and a user clicks a button which would redirect to a different page where they can add a nationality. Here is what i have so far:

```
@model WebApp.Models.ViewModels.AddPersonViewModel

<div class="container card">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddPersonPost", "Persons", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <form>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonModel.Relationship, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Relationship" })
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonModel.Comment, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Comment" })
                </div>
                <div class="col dropdown show">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PersonModel.Nationality, Model.NationalityList)

                    <input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary mt-1" value="Add Nationality" onclick="window.location='@Url.Action("GetAll", "Persons")'">

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="m-sm-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary" value="Add Person">
            </div>
        </form>
    }
</div>
```

I have tried the redirect option but when i click the button to add nationality it keeps going to the Action in the BeginForm, not to the intended Action in the button. So i was wondering 1. is this good practice to do what i am attempting to do? 2. How to go about it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not hide/show an input element where user can enter the new nation name and still submit the form ? You can toggle the visibility of this input element using javascript when user clicks on the "Other" or "Create nationality" link/button

Comment: Not related, but you have nested forms which is invalid html. If you want to redirect, then just use a link (using `@Html.ActionLink()`) but it would be better to use some javascript and ajax to create the new `Nationality` and if successful, add a new `<option>` to the `<select>`

Comment: Good catch, i did not even realize that nested forms. Appreciate the feedback. Yea i decided to go the route with having a text box be display incase they need to add a nationality or select from the drop down. But i validate to make sure either a drop down list value is selected or the new value is entered.